# How to position a div relatively to an image?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a page for a portfolio that does contain a grid that contain images with an info overlay.

Here's the link: [cyrilmoisson-dev.netlify.app](https://cyrilmoisson-dev.netlify.app/photographie/TrancheDeCake)

Is there a solution to make the overlay div exactly the same size (height and width) as the image without using something like `background: url(...);`
The problem is that images are random sized...

This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567525/how-can-i-position-a-div-relative-to-an-image) because it hasn't been resolved for me.

Here is the component code for every image:

`src/component/ImageWithInfos/ImageWithInfos.jsx`:

```
// Lazyload
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload';

// Style
import { ImageContainer, ImageSrc, ImageInfoContainer, ImageInfo } from './styles';

// Utils
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

const ImageWithInfos = ({ height, width, src, title, infos }) => (
    <LazyLoad height={height} offset={height + 100}>
        <ImageContainer height={height} width={width}>
            <ImageSrc src={src} alt={title} />
            <ImageInfoContainer>
                <ImageInfo main>{title}</ImageInfo>
                {infos.map((info) => <ImageInfo key={uuid()}>{info}</ImageInfo>)}
            </ImageInfoContainer>
        </ImageContainer>
    </LazyLoad>
);

ImageWithInfos.propTypes = {
    height: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    width: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    infos: PropTypes.array,
};

export default ImageWithInfos;
```

`src/component/ImageWithInfos/styles.js`

```
// Style
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

export const ImageContainer = styled.div`
    height: ${({ height }) => `${height}px`};
    width: ${({ width }) => `${width}px`};
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;

export const ImageSrc = styled.img`
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
`;

export const ImageInfoContainer = styled.div`
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s ease;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
        scale: 1.1;
    }
`;

export const ImageInfo = styled.span`
    padding: .2rem 1rem;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    ${({ main }) => main && css`
        font-weight: 800;
    `}
`;
```

`src/component/ImageWithInfos/index.js`

```
export { default } from './ImageWithInfos';
```

Thanks for your help.

BTW: I'm using react and styled-components, if it changes anything...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: the only thing I can think of is getting the original size of the image, calculating the ratio for each, and applying it to that image overlay.
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-original-image-size-in-javascript.php

Comment: @Paulie_D: Dear Computer Geek. Your point is absolutely valid. And you have got experience also. Indeed for future SO users this cannot be of great value if the site content changes. But Can answerer answer this kind of question based on his/her experience or not. Thank You :)

Comment: Here you go, some code snippets...

Comment: @aktoriukas This may be an option but is there no more simple solution...

Comment: @MiloMoisson can't come up with anything else. Otherwise, I would overthink the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could place both the image and the overlay in the same div and have the overlay element cover the whole parent div:

```html
<div className="parent">
  <img />
  <div className="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I already did that but the overlay div does fit the parent size and not the image size...

Comment: I read the snippets you added. At the moment, your DOM structure looks like this: `parentDiv > [img, overlayDiv]`, but you are setting a fixed height and width to parentDiv. **My idea is that parentDiv's height and width should be infered from img's height and width**. Therefore, maybe you can complexify your structure to look like `parentDiv > parentDiv2 > [img, overlayDiv]` and apply my previous snippets to parentDiv2